# Search column of JSON data in PostgreSQL table

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to store some JSON data in PostgreSQL table to use it as dynamic route generator. The migration is simple:

```
Schema::create($this->tablename, function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string("uri", 123);
    $table->json("middleware")->nullable();
    $table->string("as", 123)->nullable();
}
```

I store the data this way:

```
$a = new Route();
$a->uri = "/test1";
$a->middleware=json_encode(["auth","web"]);
$a->as = "TestController@test";
$a->save();
```

So let's say that I need to filter all the routes that have `auth` middleware. How can I do it?

When I try

```
Route::where('middleware', 'AS', 'auth')->get();
```

...I get an error. Is it possible to use it like that?

I use *Laravel 5.2* and *PostgreSQL 9.3.12*.

### Edit

If you are using *PostgreSQL 9.4* or later and have Laravel framework with version bigger than **5.2.29** you can use this syntax:

```
Route::where('middleware','@>','"auth"')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change where to whereRaw and query for json field

```
Route::whereRaw("middleware->> 'auth'")->get();
```

Or

```
Route::whereRaw("middleware::json->> 'auth'")->get();
```

Comment: Ok I got an error `Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text`

if I cast the output to boolean it works just fine `Route::whereRaw("(middleware->>'auth')::boolean")->get(); `

Comment: Actually I you can use this syntax: 

    `Route::where('middleware','@>','"auth"')->get();`

since laravel [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/0932c666192c7d27017e006c66abd66cc9eacced)